# cv2.imread and cv2.imshow return all zeros and black image

Tags: python

I've create a *.png image using PPT.

I want to use `cv2-python` to read and show it. But the `cv2.imshow` gave me a total black image with nothing on it. This is my code，I just don't know where was wrong:

```
img = cv2.imread(r"C:/Users/.../Test_shapes.png")
print img.max(),img.shape
cv2.imshow('color_image',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

p.s. the `img.shape` returns the correct shapes (881, 1803, 3). But `img.max()` returns 0.

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add images here. But with Matlab, my *.png could be successfully read and the max is 108.

Comment: If you post the the image to a 3rd party webpage, we can post it to your question via editing.

Comment: Where did you declare ``gray``?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. "gray" should be "img". I already corrected it.

Comment: I tried the code with a *.jpg image and it works! Why the *.png doesn't work???

Answer (score 6):

This normally happens, when you draw some black lines, on a presumably white canvas. Most applications export PNG with transparent background, even if the visible canvas was white.

The result is that the image consists only of black pixels and transparent pixels. Those that are transparent, usually also have an RGB value of 0.0.0 -- so if we look only at the RGB values, everything is black.

E.g. in inkscape, you can put a white rectangle below your drawing to make the PNG exporter really save some white background.

Both, default `cv2.imread("file.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` and `cv2.imread("file.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` ignore transparency, and only see the RGB values. This is bad, as the RGB value of a fully transparent pixel is meaningless.

Only `cv2.imread("file.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` can access the transparency channel. We extract the alpha, invert it, and add it back to the image. This simulates alpha on a white background:

```
img = cv2.imread("file.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
if img.shape[2] == 4:     # we have an alpha channel
  a1 = ~img[:,:,3]        # extract and invert that alpha
  img = cv2.add(cv2.merge([a1,a1,a1,a1]), img)   # add up values (with clipping)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)    # strip alpha channel

cv2.imshow('aa', img); cv2.waitKey(0); cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems cv2 is not friends with transparencies at all. Neither `cv.add()`, nor `cv2.addWeighted()` can apply an alpha channel easily.

Sorry, could not resist to dig out this unanswered zombie after 5 years. My solution works nicely, when there is only information in the alpha channel, and when information is in both, the rgb channels, and in the alpha channel.

Comment: Great, it helped me with the same problem